Stability Conditions for a Cylindrical Beam of Electrons: Analyzing Forces and Relativistic Constraints
A cylindrical beam of electrons with radius (R) and charge density ($$) is moving in vacuum. Assume the charge of the electron is (q), and at time (t=0), the velocity of the electrons is ($\vec{v}$ = (0, 0, z)), and the beam has cylindrical symmetry around the (z)-axis.
(a) Calculate the forces acting on an electron in the beam at time (t=0), assuming uniform charge density= ($_0$) ,and then when charge density is ($(r)$)
I found The electric field at a distance (r) from the axis of symmetry using a cylindrical Gaussian surface:
$$
E(r) = \frac{\rho_0}{2\epsilon_0} \vec{r}.
$$
and The magnetic field using an Ampere's loop:
$$
B(r) = \frac{\mu_0 v \rho_0}{2} \hat{\phi}.
$$
Thus, the force on an electron with charge (q) at a distance (r) from the axis is given by:
$$
\mathbf{F}(r) = q \left( \mathbf{E}(r) + \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B}(r) \right) = q \frac{\rho_0}{2} \left( \frac{1}{\epsilon_0} - \mu_0{v^2} \right) \vec{r}.
$$
when the charge density changes I defined
$$
\tilde{\rho}(r) = \int_0^r \rho(r') r' dr'.
$$
Then the electric and magnetic fields can be calculated similarly:
$$
E(r) = \frac{\tilde{\rho}(r)}{\epsilon_0 r} \hat{r}, \quad B(r) = \frac{\mu_0 v \tilde{\rho}(r)}{r} \hat{\phi}.
$$
Thus, the force is:
$$
\mathbf{F}(r) = q \left( E(r) + \mathbf{v} \times B(r) \right) = q \frac{\tilde{\rho}(r)}{r} \left( \frac{1}{\epsilon_0} - \mu_0 {v^2} \right) \hat{r}.
$$
then  I was asked  what should be the velocity of the electrons so that the beam does not disperse, meaning the total forces acting on each electron will be zero?
The force is zero if:
$$
v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon_0 \mu_0}} = c.
$$
I explained as follows
This means that the beam would need to move at the speed of light, which is clearly not  possible since an object can't reach the speed of light  . and that Transitioning to the rest frame eliminates the magnetic field; I then tried to explain why the electric field become zero , by stating that   as the speed approaches the speed of light, the charge density decreases and so does the electric field
yet I don't feel that the explanation is that accurate , would appreciate something that has more physical  intuition

Yes, transitioning to the rest frame of the electrons eliminates the magnetic field, but there is still mutual Coulomb repulsion and the beam disperses.

I then tried to explain why the electric field become zero

I assume you mean as $v \rightarrow c$ and considering the field in the electron rest-frame?
If your charge density per unit length in the "lab frame" is $\lambda$, then the charge density in the electron rest frame is $\lambda/\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor.
So indeed, in the rest frame of the electrons, the charge density tends to zero as $v \rightarrow c$ and $\gamma \rightarrow \infty$.

thank you I went and read on Lorentz factor  and this sums it up nicely pretty much what I wanted  , we did not learn Lorentz transformation nor relativity this year( the courses got shortened because of war ), so I do know how to switch frames using Lorentz transformation yet  i need to articulate myself much more in this area  to be able to use it freely
